# Смещение соседних элементов при наведении

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Вопрос: как сделать так, чтобы  при наведении соседние элементы оставались статичными?

```css
body {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1170px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

ul,
ol {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.header-wrapper {
  background-color: #212121;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
  padding: 20px 15px;
}

.header-wrapper,
.header-wrapper nav[role="navigation"] ul {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.header-wrapper nav[role="navigation"] ul li:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.header-wrapper nav[role="navigation"] ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header-wrapper nav[role="navigation"] ul li a:hover {
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  animation: menuHoverEffect .3s ease-in;
}

@keyframes menuHoverEffect {
  0% {
    padding: 5px;
  }
  50% {
    padding: 10px;
  }
  100% {
    padding: 5px;
  }
}

.header-wrapper__hamburger {
  width: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 60px;
}

.header-wrapper__hamburger span {
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 2px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.header-wrapper__hamburger span:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.header-wrapper__logo {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<header role="banner">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header-wrapper">
      <div class="header-wrapper__hamburger">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
      </div>

      <a href="#" class="header-wrapper__logo">Some text</a>

      <nav role="navigation">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте анимировать не отступы и рамку, а тень:

```css
body {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1170px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

ul,
ol {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.header-wrapper {
  background-color: #212121;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
  padding: 20px 15px;
}

.header-wrapper,
.header-wrapper nav[role="navigation"] ul {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.header-wrapper nav[role="navigation"] ul li:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.header-wrapper nav[role="navigation"] ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header-wrapper nav[role="navigation"] ul li a:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0px 0px transparent, 0 0 0px 3px #ffffff;
  animation: menuHoverEffect .3s ease-in;
}

@keyframes menuHoverEffect {
  0%,
  100% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0px 0px #212121, 0 0 0px 3px #ffffff;
  }
  50% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0px 6px #212121, 0 0 0px 9px #ffffff;
  }
}

.header-wrapper__hamburger {
  width: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 60px;
}

.header-wrapper__hamburger span {
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 2px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.header-wrapper__hamburger span:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.header-wrapper__logo {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-right: 30px;
}
```

```html
<header role="banner">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header-wrapper">
      <div class="header-wrapper__hamburger">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
      </div>

      <a href="#" class="header-wrapper__logo">Some text</a>

      <nav role="navigation">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант, через псевдоэлемент:

```css
body {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1170px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

ul,
ol {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.header-wrapper {
  background-color: #212121;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
  padding: 20px 15px;
}

.header-wrapper,
.header-wrapper nav[role="navigation"] ul {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.header-wrapper nav[role="navigation"] ul li:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.header-wrapper nav[role="navigation"] ul li a {
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header-wrapper nav[role="navigation"] ul li a:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header-wrapper nav[role="navigation"] ul li a:hover:before {
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  animation: menuHoverEffect .3s ease-in;
}

@keyframes menuHoverEffect {
  0% {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
  }
  50% {
    top: -5px;
    left: -5px;
    right: -5px;
    bottom: -5px;
  }
  100% {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
  }
}

.header-wrapper__hamburger {
  width: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 60px;
}

.header-wrapper__hamburger span {
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 2px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.header-wrapper__hamburger span:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.header-wrapper__logo {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<header role="banner">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header-wrapper">
      <div class="header-wrapper__hamburger">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
      </div>

      <a href="#" class="header-wrapper__logo">Some text</a>

      <nav role="navigation">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

P.S. Без артефактов и подергиваний.

Answer (score 0):

Простой способ добавить *margin: -5px* в @keyframes 50%:

```css
body {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1170px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

ul,
ol {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.header-wrapper {
  background-color: #212121;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
  padding: 20px 15px;
}

.header-wrapper,
.header-wrapper nav[role="navigation"] ul {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.header-wrapper nav[role="navigation"] ul li:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.header-wrapper nav[role="navigation"] ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header-wrapper nav[role="navigation"] ul li a:hover {
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  animation: menuHoverEffect .3s ease-in;
}

@keyframes menuHoverEffect {
  0% {
    padding: 5px;
  }
  50% {
    padding: 10px;
    margin: -5px;
  }
  100% {
    padding: 5px;
  }
}

.header-wrapper__hamburger {
  width: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 60px;
}

.header-wrapper__hamburger span {
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 2px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.header-wrapper__hamburger span:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.header-wrapper__logo {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<header role="banner">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header-wrapper">
      <div class="header-wrapper__hamburger">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
      </div>

      <a href="#" class="header-wrapper__logo">Some text</a>

      <nav role="navigation">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```